# react native - onclick component not coming above sibling components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a transition in which given a list of preview thumbnails, when I click on one, it scales it to the complete screen with all the additional details as required. Problem I'm having is that when I try using the properties `position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, zIndex: 2` in order to place the component's full view on top of all other sibling components like a modal, for some reason, the child component is only able to cover the area that it's child component is covering as a thumbnail.

Structure:

```
-- Parent Component containing FlatList of Child Components
-- -- Child Component 0
-- -- Child Component 1
-- -- Child Component 2
-- -- Child Component 3
-- -- Child Component 4
```

The idea is to make something similar to the way it works in the iOS App store: https://vimeo.com/272028619

And this is another illustration how I need it to work like: https://vimeo.com/272027050

And this is how it looks like right now: https://vimeo.com/272027061

How is it possible for me to cover the complete area of the Parent Component as a child component?

Answer (score 1):

Try styling your parent component as `absolute` and on each `onclick` event of your child component, toggle the `z-index`.

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute doesn't work well inside `FlatList`. You can replace your `FlatList` with `View` and set `position: absolute` to the `View` component like below:

```
data.map((item) => 
  <View style={{position: absolute}}>
    <ChildComponent item={item}>
  </View>
);
```

Now in your child component, you have to set `top` property of each card which will be sum of the heights of all the previous cards. Your applied animation will work after this.